# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called when cell selected in edit mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having an issues with a tableview when in edit mode.

The table should allow users to select multiple files in edit mode and the checkbox should be marked.

The problem I am having is didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called when deselecting a selected cell. However it is called when the cell is not selected and becomes selected.

The tableview has the following properties set

```
    self.tblFiles.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    self.tblFiles.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on deselecting you should be using

```
tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: No idea how I missed that. Thanks very much!

Comment: Much overlooked and underestimated! Thanks for reminding!